# write a python function to execute data labelling automatically in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-preprocessing

I have a column named `ARRIVAL DELAY` and based on its value I have to write a python function to execute data labelling automatically.
For eg. The value below 5 is regarded as early (0), 5 to 20 is regarded as on time (1), and above 20 is regarded as late(2).
But the function must determine the range itself for each category early, on time, and late (e.g. using bin size)
The code that I have is hardcoded at the moment.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col,lit

flightsDf = flightsDf.withColumn("multiClassArrDelay", when((flightsDf.ARRIVAL_DELAY < 5), lit(0)).when((flightsDf.ARRIVAL_DELAY >= 5) & (flightsDf.ARRIVAL_DELAY <= 20), lit(1)) \
     .otherwise(lit(2)))
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data and your requirements there are several options to calculate the boundaries between the bins.

#### Using the min and max value

The easiest option would be to take the [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.min.html) and [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.max.html) values of the column and split this range into three parts:

```python
#create some test data first
import numpy as np
data=np.concatenate((np.random.normal(10, 5, 1000),np.random.normal(25, 5, 1000)))
data=data[np.where(data >= 0)]
flightsDf=spark.createDataFrame(map(lambda d: [float(d)], data), schema=['ARRIVAL_DELAY'])

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
min,max=flightsDf.select(F.min('ARRIVAL_DELAY'), F.max('ARRIVAL_DELAY')).first()
boundaries=[(max-min)/3, (max-min)/3*2]
```

`boundaries` now contains the two values that split the range between the smallest and the largest value into three ranges with equal length. These values can now be used instead of the hardcoded values:

```python
flightsDf.withColumn('multiClassArrDelay', 
    F.when(F.col('ARRIVAL_DELAY') < boundaries[0], F.lit(0))
    .otherwise(F.when(F.col('ARRIVAL_DELAY') < boundaries[1], F.lit(1))
    .otherwise(F.lit(2))))
```

When counting the elements in each bin we get (for the test data mentioned above)

```
+------------------+-----+
|multiClassArrDelay|count|
+------------------+-----+
|                 0|  808|
|                 1|  937|
|                 2|  223|
+------------------+-----+
```

#### Using bins with equal number of elements

For some usecases it might be helpful if each bin contained (approximately) the same amount of items. Instead of using `min` and `max` [percentile_approx](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) can be used to calculate the boundaries of the bins:

```python
boundaries=flightsDf.select(F.percentile_approx('ARRIVAL_DELAY', [1/3,2/3])).first()[0]
```

With this approach we get approximately the same amount of items in each bin:

```
+------------------+-----+
|multiClassArrDelay|count|
+------------------+-----+
|                 0|  655|
|                 1|  656|
|                 2|  657|
+------------------+-----+
```

#### Using bins that are consistent with your business requirements

When running machine learning tasks it would probably the best idea to group the data into bins that make sense in the domain where the data comes from. A short haul flight that is delayed by 30 min is usually regarded differently than an intercontinental flight with the same delay.